# Service Stops after activity is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, service, process

i'm trying to make a very simple service that plays an audio file by putting a button that its onClick() ->  starts the service which in turn plays the sound.
but when i destroy the activity  the song stops ( i can't tell Service state)[that i put a toast in onDestroy method in Service class , and it didn't come out.]

Any One Can HELP ?!!

**AndroidManifest**

```
  <service android:name=".ExampleService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        ></service>
```

**ExampleService.java**

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mpService;
private final static String TAG="ExampleService";

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mpService.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mpService=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lwyashko);
    Toast.makeText(this,"*** STARTED *** ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy was Called ");
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service Destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Nullable
@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
   playService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        i=new Intent(getApplication(),ExampleService.class);
        startService(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of API 26, only foreground services will usually be allowed to run without an Activity still active. You make a service a foreground one by calling startForeground() within the service. You will need to create and provide a notification in the call. [Here's the relevant documentation page.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Thank you very much @scottt

Comment: i'll use foreground one

Answer (score 0):

Normally, after the service is started by startService, the service will not be destroyed after the activity is closed. However, if the user manually cleans up the task, the entire APP process will be closed and the Service will stop.